Laravel naming conventions confusion
As I understand the model attributes should be camelCase and the corresponding DB columns should be snake_case. But when I try
$rank = new Rank;
$rank->fullName = 'major'; //full_name column in DB
$rank->save();

it shows the error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fullName' in 'field list'

ChatGPT says it must convert the names to snake case, however it does not. What should I do? Should I create getters and setters for each attribute. E.g. setFullName and getFullName? Am I missing something?
I found that it would look nicer with $fillable, this way all the snake_case attributes would be array keys, but I want to adress them later as
echo $rank->fullName;

not
echo $rank->full_name;


By saying As I understand how did you come to this conclusion? ChatGPT gives wrong answers and recommendations most of the time, at least out of date. I never used model properties<->column names as camelCase so I'm confused.

"As I understand the model attributes should be camelCase and the corresponding DB columns should be snake_case." - According to who? While true that Class Attributes are typically in camelCase, like $person->firstName, in Laravel, the columns from your database are automatically mapped to attributes, so if your column is first_name, you access them as $person->first_name.
